# LINQ query throwing a cast exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am attempting a LINQ query in a VB.NET WPF solution that bridges two datatables and groups by a Zone.

I am receiving an "Invalid Cast Exception" on these rows:

```
.MfstCt = ZoneGroup.Count(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("ConsignmentNumber")), _
.ArticleCt = ZoneGroup.Count(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("ArticleNumber")) _
```

The error states:

> Conversion from string "B4B0158234" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

But I don't see any conversion to boolean in my query.

The field `ConsignmentNumber` is in the mfst table, and the field `ArticleNumber` is in the article table. I have added the entire query below. Can anyone help advise where I am going wrong with this?

```
Dim query = _
    From Mfst In tblMFst.AsEnumerable() _
    Join article In tblArticle.AsEnumerable() _
    On Mfst.Field(Of Integer)("PCMSConsignment_ID") Equals _
        article.Field(Of Integer)("PCMSConsignment_ID") _
    Group Mfst By Zone = Mfst.Field(Of String)("PostZone") Into ZoneGroup = Group
    Select New With _
    { _
        Key Zone, _
        .MfstCt = ZoneGroup.Count(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("ConsignmentNumber")), _
        .ArticleCt = ZoneGroup.Count(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("ArticleNumber")) _
    }

For Each x In query
    Console.WriteLine(x.Zone, x.MfstCt, x.MfstCt)
Next
```

EDIT: I have changed code to reflect correct `(Of String)` and updated the error message being received.

Comment: The exception should tell you want the actual type was - what does the exception say?

Comment: It means there is at least one row which has non-`int` or empty value for  `ConsignmentNumber` or `ArticleNumber` column.

Comment: The full exception is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occured in System.Data.DataSetExtentions.dll

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: I attempted to change the cast from integer to string (I can see what i've done there) but now I get another cast exception = "Conversion from string "B4B0158234" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."

Comment: What is ZoneGroup?  If it is an IEnumerable, then Count method expects a predicate that returns a Boolean.  Your Lambdas don't return a Boolean.  Perhaps it should be something like this:  `.MfstCt = ZoneGroup.Count(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("ConsignmentNumber") = "SomeValue")`

Answer (score 1):

LINQ's `.Count` extension method, when it takes a `Func` predicate requires the function to return a boolean. See the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The function is there to act as a predicate to chose which elements to count (for example `Function(x) x >= 20`).

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems like you should be just do something like `ZoneGroup.Count()` or if you're trying to match a particular condition `ZoneGroup.Count(Function(c) c.IsTheThingWeWant())`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Linq Count function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects a boolean comparison.  You are passing:

```
.Count(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("ConsignmentNumber"))
```

It is trying to return `c.Field(Of String)("ConsignmentNumber")` as a boolean.